Why is explicit cast of std::string to std::string_view required here?
I have written the following function template:
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

template <typename CharT,
          typename Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>>
int fun(std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> str1)
{
    return 0;
}

The idea being to be able to call the function with any type of string_view. That appears to work, in general.
However, if I try to call the function using a string, I get compilation errors:
int main()
{
    std::string s1("String 1");

    fun(s1);
}

results in
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/jeff/Projects/xxx/jkb.cpp -o /home/jeff/Projects/xxx/jkb -std=c++17 -I../include
/home/jeff/Projects/xxx/jkb.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/jeff/Projects/xxx/jkb.cpp:20:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘fun(std::string&)’
   20 |     fun(s1);
      |     ~~~^~~~
/home/jeff/Projects/xxx/jkb.cpp:6:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class CharT, class Traits> int fun(std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>)’
    6 | int fun(std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> str1)
      |     ^~~
/home/jeff/Projects/xxx/jkb.cpp:6:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/jeff/Projects/xxx/jkb.cpp:20:8: note:   ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>’
   20 |     fun(s1);
      |     ~~~^~~~


If I explicitly cast s1 to a string_view
    fun(static_cast<std::string_view>(s1));

that works.
Why does the attempt to implicitly cast the string fail to match any of the possible string_view arguments to fun fail? And why the message about string not being derived from string_view?
Thanks.

Implicit conversions aren't considered during template argument deduction

A std::string is not a std::string_view.  A C-string literal is not a std::string_view.  You'll need to cast or construct a std::string_view.

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later

The type-adjustments this line is talking about is more concerned with things like cv-qualification, references, or inheritance -- which might be the reason why it mentions inheritance in the error.
I would also add a question for you: how many different string-types are you even using? I must admit I haven't tried, but a normal std::string_view not only takes a std::string without any hassle, but a "string-literal" as well -- which I suspect might not work with your solution either.

As a final note, you could also make a type-converting wrapper for the most common types that you are using for this -- like an inline function taking a std::string_view that just calls your templated function. Something like this for each string-type that you actually use:
inline int fun(std::string_view x)
{
   return fun<char>(x);
}

Voila -- fun now takes anything that converts to a std::string_view:
fun("abc");                // works
fun(std::string("abc"));   // works
fun(L"abc");               // fails: no wrapper for wstring stuff
fun(L"abc"sv);             // works (hits the template directly)


The goal here is to write a function that can take any of the string_view types (string_view, wstring_view, etc.), and be able call it with minimal effort. Instead of templates, do I need to write separate versions of fun, one for each string_view type? That seems error-prone. Is there another way to accomplish this?

@jkb That's why I brought up the wrapper functions: a simple inline int fun(std::string_view x) { return fun<char>(x); } should do the trick, and still keep your (presumably complicated) fun in just one place. fun will now take anything that converts into a ``std::string_view`...

@jkb Just add an overload for string literals that calls the string_view version: template <typename CharT, std::size_t N> int fun(CharT(&str1)[N]) { return fun(std::string_view{str1}); }

Thanks, folks. I appreciate the suggestions.
